# Firebase phone auth detect wrong sms code

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I don't think this is platform-specific, but I am implementing Firebase phone auth in a Flutter app and I'm not really sure how I can detect that someone entered an invalid SMS code. In the scope of the `verifyPhoneNumber()` method in `Firebase.instance`, where can I detect this? Will this be handled in the `verificationFailed()` callback, or is it not something we will know until we try to log in using `signInWithCredential()` and it fails?

--EDIT--

Upon more investigation, it looks like no exceptions would get thrown, and the only thing that would happen is that `signInWithCredential()` will return a null `user` object. The best solution I can think of is just to wait for 5 seconds (or something) and see if we get a non-null `user`. Anyone have any better ideas?

Also, note that my development device doesn't have cell connectivity, so I am using a fake testing number through the Firebase console. This means that the `verificationCompleted()` callback won't get called, and `codeAutoRetrievalTimeout()` gets called instead, forcing manual SMS code entry. Hope that gives some better background.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Upon more experimentation, I found that an error will get thrown in `signInWithCredential()`. Here's some dart-specific code that shows how this works:

```dart
AuthResult authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(_authCredential).catchError((error) {
    // do something with the error
    print(error);
});
```

The error in Flutter with an invalid code is `PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_VERIFICATION_CODE, The sms verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code sms and be sure use the verification code provided by the user., null)`

Comment: No, it still gets thrown

Comment: Thats because it logins automatically, but doesnt redirect to home